# iOS iPhone Modal Popup Changes Underlying View Back To Storyboard State

Tags: iphone, ios, modal-dialog, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I faced a problem with modal segue in my iPhone application. I made a slidable side panel that can be shown by pan gesture. Originally the side panel is a half visible and "Add" button there is hidden and not accessible by user.

Making side panel visible user can hit "Add" button that will segue Modal view with a dialog.

My problem here: when modal popup appears it changes underlying view to story board state (makes side panel half visible), but I need underlying view stay in same look as it is.

View controller objects stay same. As expected view unload and load are not happening and view appear and disappear happening.

Will be great if someone can help me with investigation idea.

Adding some screenshots.
Here is original view state:
[image: original view state]

View with opened side panel:

[image: opened side panel]

Clicking "Add" button shows modal popup. I made screen shot in the middle of modal popup slide. As you can see underlying side panel becomes closed as in original state, but supposed to be opened.

[image: modal popup middle opened]

Dismissing modal by cancel view stays in original state.

Thank you,
Dmitry

Comment: It's hard to visualize this, could you add a picture or some code?

Comment: Great pictures! Couple of thoughts I had for investigation. Try commenting out the functionality off your add button, make it print to console. This will make sure that the touch event isn't causing the issue itself (conflicting touch gestures possibly?). Put a breakpoint in the code that moves your slide out, see who's moving it back if possible.